# What is the Big-O complexity of a MySQL SELECT statement that uses BETWEEN clause?

Tags: mysql, select, innodb, big-o, between

I am interested in theoretical Big-O analysis of the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, value FROM MyTable WHERE lat BETWEEN %s AND %s AND lon BETWEEN %s AND %s;
```

In particular, I would like to know how the BETWEEN clause affects the complexity of this query.

---

MySQL version is 5.1

MyTable defintion:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, \
    value DECIMAL(12,9) NOT NULL, \
    lat DECIMAL(9,6), \
    lon DECIMAL(9,6), \
PRIMARY KEY(id(50)), \
INDEX(lat, lon)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Describe MyTable;
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | varchar(255)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| value    | decimal(12,9)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lat      | decimal(9,6)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| lon      | decimal(9,6)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT id, value FROM MyTable WHERE lat BETWEEN '40' AND '60' AND lon BETWEEN '-10' AND '10';
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | MyTable    | ALL  | lat           | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 |    42.86 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: doesn't that partly depend on how keys are indexed ?

Comment: Possibly. How can I find that out to update the question?

Comment: Well depends how you created the tables. if you are unsure, I recommend using DB Artisan, which connects to most databases. You'll be able to browse indexes (if any) and once we know which keys are indexed, then we can start discussing complexity (do you need to scan all keys to find one ? do you get one by hash code ? etc...)

Comment: I created the table as described in the question. I would think that means there is an index on (lat, lon)?

Comment: Not only the fact that there is an index matters, Type of indexes matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type = ALL` means that this query performs a full scan on the table. `key = NULL` means that no index is used. In this case it is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of rows.

As for `BETWEEN`, it is the same as performing two compare opearations (`>=` and `<=`). If those are executed on indexes (which are [B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) in MySQL), it is `O(log n)` in both average and worst cases. Because B-Tree stores values sequentially, such things as range searches are very fast.

As I know for secondary indexes, InnoDB stores primary ID together with secondary index values, so if you do `SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE lat ... AND lon ...` (selecting only `id`), it wouldn't even look inside the actual rows.

Find out more here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html

For your case, I recommend you to set some index on lat and lon fields (separately) and experiment which works best for your data. Maybe it is even worth to add extra fields which will contain rouded lat and lon values (as SMALL INTs) to speed up index - in that case you can add multicolumn index on that fields.

Comment: Thanks for these insights! Any idea why the multi-columns (lat, lon) index is not used? Is it because the table is almost empty at the moment and it would be used if there were more rows?

Comment: If you create a compound primary key on (id, value) you can still select both columns and don't fetch actual rows during the range scan.

Comment: @MaxOsowski It is because in this particular case optimizer decides that using this index is less effective when full scan - I don't know exactly why. And yes, if there were more rows, it could use it. Also, there is a [Index Merge optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-optimization.html), which might give better results in your case (if you have two separate indices for lat and lon).